# How to set Expectation for Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, xunit

Using *Rhino Mocks*:

```
var list = MockRepository.GenerateMock<List<Foo>>();
list.Expect(e => e.Any(Arg<Func<Foo, bool>>.Is.Anything)).Return(false);
```

It throws

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: predicate

How do I write this well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Any` is an `Extension` method which means the method is a `static` method. You cannot fake `static` methods using `Rhino Mocks`.

It's a common mistake to put an expectation like this for asserting.

Actually you don't have to fake the `List` (It is a DS which means the behaviour won't impact the test), just create an instance of the real class and use it , then verify that the flow of empty list behave correctly.(do `Assert` on the things which should be happen)